# Infinite border color loop

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I want to have this effect, but not on the whole body background but just on the border of one of my div's. ( http://jsfiddle.net/ANMPt/ )

```
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
    0%   { background:red; }
    50%  { background:green;}
    100% { background:red; }
}
@-moz-keyframes blink {
    0%   { background:red; }
    50%  { background:green;}
    100% { background:red; }
}
@-ms-keyframes blink {
    0%   { background:red; }
    50%  { background:green;}
    100% { background:red; }
}
body{
 -webkit-animation: blink 1s infinite;
 -moz-animation:    blink 1s infinite;
 -ms-animation:     blink 1s infinite;
}
```

How do I target just the border?

Or: if anyone has a better solution to get an infinite loop of changing border colors in CSS or JavaScript: i am all ears :-)

Thanks!

Comment: So why are you applying the animation on `<body>`? There's also no `<div>` in your fiddle demo. Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/ANMPt/161/

Comment: Warning: never use only vendor prefixes! If you don't include the standard syntax, the code won't on future versions of those browsers, nor on browsers you don't consider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are applying it to the `body`! Do it for `div`

```
div {
     -webkit-animation: blink 1s infinite;
     -moz-animation:    blink 1s infinite;
     -ms-animation:     blink 1s infinite;
}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/ANMPt/160/

But, if you say it is for border, do it for `border-color` not for `background`!

```
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
        0%   { border-color:red; }
        50%  { border-color:green;}
        100% { border-color:red; }
}
@-moz-keyframes blink {
        0%   { border-color:red; }
        50%  { border-color:green;}
        100% { border-color:red; }
}
@-ms-keyframes blink {
        0%   { border-color:red; }
        50%  { border-color:green;}
        100% { border-color:red; }
}
div {
     -webkit-animation: blink 1s infinite;
     -moz-animation:    blink 1s infinite;
     -ms-animation:     blink 1s infinite;
     border: 2px solid;
}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/ANMPt/167/

Answer (score 2):

Animate `border-color` instead of `background`:

```
@keyframes blink {
    0%   { border-color: red; }
    50%  { border-color: green;}
    100% { border-color: red; }
}
body {
    border: 15px solid;
    animation: blink 1s infinite;
}
```

<sup>Some browsers may need vendor prefixes</sup>

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ANMPt/164/)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/ANMPt/162/

Change it to border-color.

```
            @-webkit-keyframes blink {
                    0%   { border-color:red; }
                    50%  { border-color:green;}
                    100% { border-color:red; }
            }
            @-moz-keyframes blink {
                    0%   { border-color:red; }
                    50%  { border-color:green;}
                    100% { border-color:red; }
            }
            @-ms-keyframes blink {
                    0%   { border-color:red; }
                    50%  { border-color:green;}
                    100% { border-color:red; }
            }
            body{
                 -webkit-animation: blink 1s infinite;
                 -moz-animation:    blink 1s infinite;
                 -ms-animation:     blink 1s infinite;

                 border: 20px solid red;  /* cant animate border without a border... */

                 height: 200px; / * for illustration purpose */
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply it to the right property (`border-color` instead of `background`) and to the right element (it's better to use a `class` selector, so the effect can be applied to any element instead that only to divs).

Also don't forget to use (always as last) the default `@keyframe` syntax other than the prefixed ones.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ANMPt/166/)

HTML

```xml
<div class="animatedBorder"></div>
```

CSS

```css
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
        0%   { border-color:red; }
        50%  { border-color:green;}
        100% { border-color:red; }
}
@-moz-keyframes blink {
        0%   { border-color:red; }
        50%  { border-color:green;}
        100% { border-color:red; }
}
@-ms-keyframes blink {
        0%   { border-color:red; }
        50%  { border-color:green;}
        100% { border-color:red; }
}
@keyframes blink {
        0%   { border-color:red; }
        50%  { border-color:green;}
        100% { border-color:red; }
}

.animatedBorder{
     -webkit-animation: blink 1s infinite;
     -moz-animation:    blink 1s infinite;
     -ms-animation:     blink 1s infinite;
}

div.animatedBorder{
    margin: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**The FIX** **is Animating `border-color` instead of `background`**

But if you need to add this effect to a div

simply add a `div`inside the `body`

then change the `background` in css to `border-color` property

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/s4ayc6st/)

```
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
        0%   { border-color:red; }
        50%  { border-color:green;}
        100% { border-color:red; }
}
@-moz-keyframes blink {
        0%   { border-color:red; }
        50%  { border-color:green;}
        100% { border-color:red; }
}
@-ms-keyframes blink {
        0%   { border-color:red; }
        50%  { border-color:green;}
        100% { border-color:red; }
}
div{
    border:2px solid;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
     -webkit-animation: blink 1s infinite;
     -moz-animation:  blink 1s infinite;
     -ms-animation:   blink 1s infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
        0%   { border-color:red; }
        50%  { border-color:green;}
        100% { border-color:red; }
}
@-moz-keyframes blink {
        0%   { border-color:red; }
        50%  { border-color:green;}
        100% { border-color:red; }
}
@-ms-keyframes blink {
        0%   { border-color:red; }
        50%  { border-color:green;}
        100% { border-color:red; }
}
div{
    border:solid 1px red;
     -webkit-animation: blink 1s infinite;
     -moz-animation:    blink 1s infinite;
     -ms-animation:     blink 1s infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace all occurrences of `background` with `border-color` and then use them on your div-element instead of the body.

You probably have to define a border for the div first (like `#000000 1px solid`) in order to animate it.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ANMPt/165/

You need to change the style for the animation definitions:

```
    0%   { border-color:red; }
    50%  { border-color:green;}
    100% { border-color:red; }
```

And define a border for your div:

```
#myDiv{
    height: 300px;
    width:300px;
    border-width:5px;
    border-style:solid;
     -webkit-animation: blink 1s infinite;
     -moz-animation:    blink 1s infinite;
     -ms-animation:     blink 1s infinite;
}
```